# subprocess.getoutput('netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state') in python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I try to get Windows Firewall Status with this :

```
FW = []
result = subprocess.getoutput('netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state').split()
for x in result[5::6]:
    FW.append(x)
return FW
```

And my result is :

```
['ON', 'ON', 'ON']
```

But i can't do it with Python 2. When i run this with Python 2 error show up that no function subprocess.getoutput though i was install and import subprocess module. But it working fine with Python 3. Can anybody show me how to get same result in Python 2 ?

Comment: did you try `subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)`.

Comment: Can you test with `commands.getoutput('netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state').split()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `check_output` function of `subprocess` module. The function 
returns the output of the command you supply. `shell=True` specifies that `command` is a string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell. If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>>
>>> result = subprocess.check_output('netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state', shell=True)
>>>
>>> FW = list()
>>> for x in result.split()[5::6]:
...     FW.append(x)
...
>>> FW
['ON', 'ON', 'ON']
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html says:
The `subprocess` module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results. Using the `subprocess` module is preferable to using the commands module.